# Flex Arraycollection filter

Tags: apache-flex

I am working in Flex.

I have an arraycollection which is used to fill a tilelist with images.

I am using filter method of arraycollection to filter out certain images from tilelist based on a selected value from combobox.

The issue is that when the images are filtered out they just vanish suddenly. 

But I want to give some effect to them when they are filtered out, say slow fade effect or zoom effect. I tried removedEffect, hideEffect etc. but in vain.

Can anyone please help me out. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add effects to the TileList, you can see some examples at [Using data effects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=behaviors_09.html)
article.

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried the example u gave but it is not working in my case. my tilelist's dataprovider (arraycollection) is getting dynamically filtered and the images thus rendered vanishes out abruptly without any effect. any idea?

Comment: If I remember well, this indeed didn't work with filtering, I've used it a long time ago, but I think what we did finally was manually add/delete items form the dataProvider.